# Another await which doesn't wait

Tags: c#, uwp, async-await, task

Usually I don't post, I read and found my answers.

But this time despite the fact that I've found dozen posts about async/await problem it seems no solution worked for my case (or I at least didn't understand).

My code is really long, so I Don't put it here in it's entirety, but it looks like this:
I've a task which is writing in a database:

```
public async Task WatchSpool(Button buttonSend)
{
    LoadOptions();
    //SpoolWatcher spoolWatcher = new SpoolWatcher(this, buttonSend);
    SpoolWatcher spoolWatcher = new SpoolWatcher(this);
    spoolWatcher.OnSpoolWatcherException += OnSpoolWatcherException;
    Task thread = new Task(spoolWatcher.Run);
    spoolWatcherMustStop = false;
    thread.Start();
    //spoolWatcher.Run();
}
```

Then another one which counts the number of records in a specific table in the database:

```
public int CountWaitingRecords(string table)
{
    int WaitingRecords = 0;
    try
    {
        using (SqliteConnection connexion = new SqliteConnection("Filename = spool.db"))
        {
            connexion.Open();
            using (SqliteCommand cmd = new SqliteCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count FROM " + table, connexion))
            {
                SqliteDataReader rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                rs.Read();

                WaitingRecords = rs.GetInt32(rs.GetOrdinal("Count"));

                rs.Dispose();
                cmd.Dispose();
                connexion.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return WaitingRecords;
}
```

And both of them are called here:

```
private async void buttonSendSelectedItems_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //things doing fine here…

        //Start spoolWatcher
        batigest = new Batigest(localFolder + "\\spool.db");
        batigest.OnSpoolWatcherException += new OnSpoolWatcherExceptionHandler(batigest_OnSpoolWatcherException);
        //Alternative code
        //Task.Run(() => batigest.WatchSpool(Envoyer)).Wait();
        //Actual code
        Task task = batigest.WatchSpool(Envoyer);
        await task;
        //Another alternative code
        //task.Wait();

        //Here I count how many rows I've in my table
        LocalDB localDB = new LocalDB(localFolder.Path.ToString() + "\\spool.db");
        int count = localDB.CountWaitingRecords("MouvementStock");
        if (count > 0)
        {
            Envoyer.Content = "Envoyer (" + count + ")";
            Envoyer.IsEnabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Envoyer.Content = "Envoyé!";
        }

        //Other things doing fine here…

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Envoyer.IsEnabled = true;
        Envoyer.Content = "Erreur!";
        InterpretException("InventoryView2.buttonSendSelectedItems_Click()", ex);
    }
}
```

The thing is: before I start counting how many rows I've in my database I should wait that task has finished.
But I can't succeed.
So if someone can told me what I'm doing wrong I'll appreciate.

Comment: you don't await in WatchSpool, you simply run a task. you may want to return that task and remove "async" or await that task.

Comment: `await` works. Tasks are not *threads* though, they are jobs that run on threads. If `await` seems to not ... await, it's because the task is already complete. Check `WatchSpool` for example. Where does it await for `spoolWatcher.Run` to finish? Nowhere. It just fires that method and never checks to see what happened. There should be a compiler warning saying the method doesn't have any `await` statement and will execute synchronously

Comment: By Any chance you didn't forget the await ? Cause in your code i only can see the async but none  await! or i´m not seeing well!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This piece of code has some problems:

```
public async Task WatchSpool(Button buttonSend)
{
    SpoolWatcher spoolWatcher = new SpoolWatcher(this);
    spoolWatcher.OnSpoolWatcherException += OnSpoolWatcherException;
    Task thread = new Task(spoolWatcher.Run);
    thread.Start();
}
```

First of all, a `Task` is not a thread, so naming it as such is misleading and wrong.

Secondly, the `Task` constructor must be avoided. Assuming that `SpoolWatcher.Run` is not a `Task`, you  should be using `Task.Run`:

```
Task runner = Task.Run(() => spoolWatcher.Run());
```

Third and most importantly, you are not `await`ing for it to finish, so `WatchSpool` will return almost immediately.

```
public async Task WatchSpool(Button buttonSend)
{
    SpoolWatcher spoolWatcher = new SpoolWatcher(this);
    spoolWatcher.OnSpoolWatcherException += OnSpoolWatcherException;
    await Task.Run(() => spoolWatcher.Run());
}
```

As a general note, `Task`-returning methods should be suffixed with Async, so it should be `WatchSpoolAsync`.

Comment: You're absolutely right ! I've changed my code as you explained and it works as it should. Many thanks !

Comment: as a general optimisation to this, instead of `await Task.Run(() ...`, return it directly instead - `return Task.Run(() ...` - and change the method signature from `async Task` to `Task`. Avoids the creation of an unnecessary Task.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake If you meant that you avoid the creation of an unnecessary state machine, you are (mostly) correct. You may want to read this: [Eliding Async and Await by @StephenCleary](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Comment: Five year later this post still help me. (:-)